# I want to get source code from asp page and create html page

Tags: asp-classic

I want to read the source code from a .asp page on my server and then create a html page from that.

I read somewhere that you can do it with webrequest but I can´t find it.

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot read the actual server-side code from an ASP page, but you can get the resulting html of the page.  Here's a good article on it:

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-read-the-contents-of-a-remote-web-page.html

And here's a snippet from that site to get you started -- there are other posts on SO about this as well:

```
<% 
    url = "http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage.asp" 
    set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
    xmlhttp.send "" 
    Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
    set xmlhttp = nothing 
%>
```